# JSON.Encode to produce new Date(yyy, MM, dd) datetime

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I use **chap-tim JS** component (http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/timeline.html)  that accepts only the following JSON format:

```
    data = [
        {
            'start': new Date(2010, 7, 26),
            'content': 'test    '
        }
    ];
```

I have no problem with all other values accept date ...
It will not accept any other format and i have no idia how to emmit the `new Date(2010, 7, 26)` format.

I use this to set the JSON data in a hidden field and then `$.parseJSON` to parse it

```
@Html.Hidden("timeline-data", Json.Encode(Model.GanntItems));
```

and then:

```
$.parseJSON($("#timeline-data").val());
```

but it emits the following `"/Date(1388728800000)/"`  and its now good...

any way to overcome this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to parse it in Javascript like following:

```
 value = new Date(parseInt(value.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/",""), 10));
```